# Saving data in the database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save data in the database using Entity Framework and this code, but I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
> at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
> at GDEProject.Pages.Profile.Update_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\RATAU\Documents\Projects\GDEProject\GDEProject\GDEProject\Pages\Profile.aspx.cs:line 48

This is the code I am using:

```
public partial class Profile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        Entities2 db = new Entities2();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    PROFILE user = new PROFILE();
                    user.IdNumber = IdNumber.Text;
                    user.PersalNumber = ParselNumber.Text;
                    user.Title = Title.Text;
                    user.Initials = Initial.Text;
                    user.Name = FirstName.Text;
                    user.Surname = LastName.Text;
                    user.Age = Age.Text; 
                    user.Race = Race.Text;
                    user.EmailAddress = Email.Text;
                    user.CellPhone = Phonenumber.Text;
                    user.TelephoneNumber = Telephone.Text;
                    user.Nationality = dropNationality.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    user.Gender = dropGender.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    user.Disability = Disability.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    user.DisabilityType = DisabilityType.Text;
                 
                    db.PROFILEs.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    ErrorMessage.Text = "saved";
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    ErrorMessage.Text = ("error" + ee);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text="modelstate failed";
            }
}
```

the class of profile is as follows:

```
 public partial class PROFILE
    {
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public string IdNumber { get; set; }
        public string PersalNumber { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Disability { get; set; }
        public string DisabilityType { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please assist

Comment: Well - it tells you *See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.* - and **have you looked** at the `EntityValidationErrors` property of the exception, to see what details it provides??

Comment: Can you post PROFILE class pls?

Comment: i have edited the post you can see the class for profile

Comment: Unrelated: `public string Age { get; set; }` Are you ready to increase this value every year in each profile? Save birthday and have age calculated.

Comment: Please add the contents of the "ValidationErrors"-property of the exception.

Comment: Has the Table a Primary Key? However, you can see the validation errors capturing the exception in a catch(Exception ex) block, when you get into the catch in the debug mode, add ex (the exception) on he watch tab, you'll see more properties and diving in onto them, you'll find entityvalidationerrors.